# How to show default values (in datatables plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 columns in my datatable, I have to show the data such that the rows which are contains 1st column value 'more than 2' (My first column is Count the values are in between 1 to 10) and the 3rd column value more than 20 (third column is percentage values are in between 0 to 100) by default.. after these values remaining values should present.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution.. But you can try like this -

```
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM 'tablename' WHERE col1 > 2 AND col3 > 20 ";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM 'tablename' WHERE col1 < 2 OR col3 < 20 ";
```

?>

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking about database table, i  added a plugin datatables in my javascript there are two options to show the data either in asc or dsc i didn't find any solution to my problem Reference link: https://datatables.net/